# How to load gltf models in RCA-typescipt+babylonjs project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babylonjs

I am trying to load .gltf model file in RCA-typescipt project but fails.

I ceate a .tsx file named SceneComponent, which includes engine, scene, and canvas:

```
    /* eslint-disable */
    import { Engine, Scene } from "@babylonjs/core";
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    /* eslint-disable */

    export default (props:any) => {
      const reactCanvas = useRef(null);
      const { antialias, engineOptions, adaptToDeviceRatio, sceneOptions, onRender, onSceneReady, ...rest } = props;

      useEffect(() => {
        if (reactCanvas.current) {
          const engine = new Engine(reactCanvas.current, antialias, engineOptions, adaptToDeviceRatio);
          const scene = new Scene(engine, sceneOptions);
          if (scene.isReady()) {
            props.onSceneReady(scene);
          } else {
            scene.onReadyObservable.addOnce((scene) => props.onSceneReady(scene));
          }

          engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
            if (typeof onRender === "function") {
              onRender(scene);
            }
            scene.render();
          });

          const resize = () => {
            scene.getEngine().resize();
          };

          if (window) {
            window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
          }

          return () => {
            scene.getEngine().dispose();

            if (window) {
              window.removeEventListener("resize", resize);
            }
          };
        }
      }, [reactCanvas]);

      return <canvas ref={reactCanvas} {...rest} />;
    };
```

Then I use this component in my App.tsx file:

```
    /* eslint-disable */
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import { FreeCamera, Vector3, HemisphericLight, MeshBuilder, SceneLoader, Scene, Engine, AssetsManager } from '@babylonjs/core';
    import "@babylonjs/loaders/glTF";
    import { Nullable } from '@babylonjs/core/types';
    import SceneComponent from './components/SceneComponent';
    /* eslint-disable */

    import model from "./assets/model2/scene.gltf";

    const App: React.FC = () => {

      const onSceneReady = (scene: any) => {

        const canvas = scene.getEngine().getRenderingCanvas();
        const camera = new FreeCamera("camera1", new Vector3(0, 5, -10), scene);
        camera.setTarget(Vector3.Zero());
        camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
        const light = new HemisphericLight("light", new Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
        light.intensity = 0.7;

        // MeshBuilder.CreateBox("box", {}, scene);
        // console.log(scene)
        // SceneLoader.Append("./assets/model2/", "scene.gltf", scene, function (scene) {
        //   console.log(scene);
        // });
        SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync(
          "",
          "./assets/model2/",
          "scene.gltf",
          scene,
        );
        console.log(scene)
      };

      const onRender = () => {

      };

      return (
        <div>
          <SceneComponent antialias onSceneReady={onSceneReady} onRender={onRender} id="my-canvas" />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

But When I tried to load gltf models in App.tsx, neither SceneLoader.Append() method nor SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync() method can I load gltf model successfully, it showed nothing:
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZUNl.png)

If I just create a box in the scene with `MeshBuilder.CreateBox("box", {}, scene);`, the model can be seen   :
[piture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13kNl.png)

So how can I load gltf model file successfully? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I see it asked a lot in the main forum.  You need to make sure that your model path is relative to your /public folder (and that your assets are in that folder as well).  The public folder is `./` on a running CRA.

If you are unsure then have a look in your Network tab in Developer Tools and it's possible that your model is being served as an index.html file and in the console there is often an error logged as well about parsing model file.